# Xamarin Hot Restart

Tags: xamarin.ios

In following the steps to set up Xamarin Hot Restart (below), I could not get the "Download All Profiles" button to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart

Operation just never completes. I likely don't have the correct permissions from our Apple Store admins. What permissions should I ask for to all this step to work? Or is there something else to try? I was able to manually download our main provisioning profile, but I don't know where to put it on a PC.

I also tried manually selecting the provisioning profile in the iOS project's properties. The only one I have has an odd name: "Unknown (Name of Our Main Provisioning Profile)". I went through the set up for my iPad and after seeing it in the deployment target drop-down, tried to deploy and debug on the iPad. The error I get is "No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile 'Name of Our Main Provisioning Profile'". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to manually download our main provisioning profile, but I don't know where to put it on a PC.

You need to install certificate and provisioning profile on mac first , and then enter your Apple Developer account credentials in vs for windows (Tools-Options-Xamarin- Apple Accounts ) ,at last select a development team using the dropdown menu in order to enable [automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos) in the project.

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#initial-setup

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot do automatic provisioning. Our Apple accounts are locked down by our IT department. We have to manually provision our machines. Any suggestions for that direction?

Comment: The steps are identical  , do you see the corresponding  signing identity and provisioning profile after you select `manual provisioning` option ?

Comment: I am getting the corresponding distribution provision profile after selecting the signing identity. But still, I am getting * No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile* error after running my application in release mode.